# Windows Phone using accept-encoding gzip compression in webclient

Tags: windows-phone-7, post, gzip, webclient

I need to post data to server, and get compressed data back from it.

I am using windows phone 7 sdk.

I read that it can be done using SharpGIS or Coding4Fun toolkit.

They use WebClient (AFAIK).

can anyone help me?

Here's what I need to do-

1. Post data(XML) to url
2. Get compressed data (only GZip supported by server) in the form of xml string/stream
3. deserialise the xml data received

and the methods should be awaitable.

Answer (score 1):

When I had to do this in wp7, I

1. Created a Portable Class Library project within my solution
2. Nuget the HTTP client library at https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http (Install-Package Microsoft.Net.Http)
3. Nuget http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/ (Install-Package Microsoft.Bcl.Async ) and add to your PCL and UI solution

With in the portable class library

```
public class PostData
{
    public async Task<T> TestMe<T>(XElement xml)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler
        {
            AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip
                                     | DecompressionMethods.Deflate
        });

        var response = await client.PostAsync("https://requestUri", CreateStringContent(xml));

        var responseString = await response.RequestMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        //var responseStream = await response.RequestMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        //var responseByte = await response.RequestMessage.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseString);
    }

    private HttpContent CreateStringContent(XElement xml)
    {
        return new StringContent(xml.ToString(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");
    }
}
```

Comment: The link  https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http says that it only supports windows phone 7.5, 8 Not windows phone 7/7.1
Is it possible to use it for projects targetting WP 7.1

Comment: @user2653208 WP 7.1 and 7.5 are the same OS. 7.1 was just renamed 7.5 for commercial reasons. And you don't need to worry about WP 7.0 as it's completely obsolete. WP 7.0 devices can't even connect to the marketplace anymore.

Answer (score 1):

WebClient and HttpWebRequest for C4F toolkit are supported.  HttpClient doesn't exist without http client library currently in WP.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Windows 8, which means Windows Phone SDK is only on VS 2010, which doesn't support the Microsoft HttpClient.

There's a NuGet package [Delay.GZipWebClient](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Delay.GzipWebClient) written by an MS dev that adds simple support for it.  So far it's worked like a charm.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2012/04/19/quot-if-i-have-seen-further-it-is-by-standing-on-the-shoulders-of-giants-quot-an-alternate-implementation-of-http-gzip-decompression-for-windows-phone.aspx